# Buffering concat map input

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm trying to find a way, how I can buffer data on concatMap input before a previous observable completes.

It's better to explain it on my real example.

I have an application using redux-observable.

There is an action `validate`

```js
const validate = updatedDataIds => ({
  type: VALIDATE,
  payload: { updatedDataIds },
});
```

I want to buffer updatedDataIds array and decrease calls of `longTimePostAjaxFunction`.

```js
export const validateEpic = (action$, state$, { longTimePostAjaxFunction }) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(VALIDATE),
    map(({ payload: { updatedDataIds } }) => updatedDatapointIds),
    // I want to buffer longTimePostAjaxFunction here until previous observable (longTimePostAjaxFunction) completes
    map(flatten),
    concatMap(updatedDataIds =>
      longTimePostAjaxFunction('validate/url', {
        updatedDataIds,
      }).pipe(
        map(validateFulfilled),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Do you have any idea how can I solve this issue?

Comment: So let's say `X` is emitted, and `longTimePostAjaxFunction` will use `X` as an argument. In the meanwhile, if `Y, Z, W` are emitted but the previous `longTimePostAjaxFunction` has not completed yet, you want to buffer `Y, Z, W` so the next `longTimePostAjaxFunction` call will have `Y, Z, W`. Did I get this right?

Comment: Not really clear what goal you are trying to achieve, but maybe try `zip`? It returns some sort of pairs of provided observables

Comment: @AndreiGătej yes you are right

Comment: @cuddlemeister I have only one observable but `concatMap` doesn't subscribe to next input before previous completes. I don't get it. Can you write an example?

Comment: `concatMap` does buffer emissions from source until an inner Observable completes. But it's hard to say what behavior you want.

Comment: @martin I want to merge data from these buffered emissions and emit only one emission when an inner Observable completes

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve your problem is with a stream that emits every time `longTimePostAjaxFunction` resolves. For instance (though there are probably better options), you could buffer the id stream on `action$.pipe(ofType('READY_FOR_IDS')`, and flatten the ready action into the stream of AJAX results.

```
export const validateEpic = (action$, state$, { longTimePostAjaxFunction }) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(VALIDATE),
    map(({ payload: { updatedDataIds } }) => updatedDatapointIds),
    buffer(action$.pipe(ofType('READY_FOR_IDS')),
    map(flatten),
    concatMap(updatedDataIds =>
      longTimePostAjaxFunction('validate/url', {
        updatedDataIds,
      }).pipe(
        map(validateFulfilled)
      ),
    ),
    concatMap(action => [action, { type: 'READY_FOR_IDS' }])
  );
```

Comment: the problem is you want to validate only if some action with type of `VALIDATE` was emitted..

Comment: I post my current solution to explain

Comment: I'm not sure I see the problem. The behavior I show above is triggered only by `VALIDATE` actions.

Answer (score 0):

My current (shitty) solution is:

buffer:

```js
..
   map(({ payload: { updatedDataIds } }) => updatedDataIds),
        buffer(action$.pipe(ofType(VALIDATION_START))),
        map(flatten),
..
```

buffering logic:

```js
export const pendingValidate = action$ =>
  mergeMap(() =>
    action$.pipe(
      ofType(VALIDATE, VALIDATE_FULFILLED),
      map(({ type }) => type),
      scan(
        ([gate], currentAction) => {
          if (currentAction === VALIDATE) {
            if (gate === 'open') return ['closed', true];
            return ['waiting', false];
          }

          if (gate === 'waiting' && currentAction === VALIDATE_FULFILLED) {
            return ['closed', true];
          }

          return ['open', false];
        },
        ['open', false],
      ),
      filter(([, shouldValidate]) => shouldValidate),
      map(() => ({ type: VALIDATION_START })),
    ),
  ),
);
```